# PBS/Torque - Couldn't delete completed job status information

Tags: pbs

The command 'qstat -a' outputs lots of lines of information for completed jobs all with status 'C'. It seems that they will stay forever. How to cleanup these unneeded job information since those jobs are already 'completed'? Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO, user2884311.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use qdel to delete all my jobs at once, not one at a time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857807/use-qdel-to-delete-all-my-jobs-at-once-not-one-at-a-time)

Answer (score 3):

This is controlled by the qmgr parameter keep_completed. keep_completed specifies a number of seconds after completion a job should continue to be visible. If you would like to immediately delete a job without waiting this amount of time, you can execute

```
qdel -p <jobid>
```

Comment: Is there also a way to delete all of them at once?

Answer (score 2):

Type `qstat -r` to get only the running jobs

Comment: Is there a way to get running or queued?