# Use qdel to delete all my jobs at once, not one at a time

Tags: ssh, cluster-computing, jobs

This is a rather simple question but I haven't been able to find an answer.

I have a large number of jobs running in a cluster (>20) and I'd like to delete them all and start over.

According to [this site](https://wiki.duke.edu/display/SCSC/Using+qdel) I should be able to just do:

```
qdel -u netid
```

to get rid of them all, but in my case that returns:

```
qdel: invalid option -- 'u'
usage: qdel [{ -a | -c | -p | -t | -W delay | -m message}] [<JOBID>[<JOBID>]|'all'|'ALL']...
   -a -c, -m, -p, -t, and -W are mutually exclusive
```

which obviously indicates that the command does not work.

Just to check, I did:

```
qstat -u <username>
```

and I do get a list of all my jobs, but:

```
qdel -u <username>
```

also fails.

Comment: is this NQS queuing system?

Comment: @Sigismondo sorry, I'm not sure what that means. I have very little knowledge with cluster managing (which I don't), I just use it.

Comment: why does `qdel -u <username>` fail?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

Found the answer buried in an [old supercluster.org thread](http://www.supercluster.org/pipermail/torqueusers/2009-June/009153.html):

```
qselect -u <username> | xargs qdel
```

Worked flawlessly.

Comment: Is there a way how to skip completed jobs? This solution does work, but outputs a great portion of errors of qdel trying to kill completed jobs..

Comment: Mmm I don't really know, sorry.

Comment: Thanks. Just in addition for UGE the option is up-case:  qselect -U <user_list>

Comment: link is back online

Comment: Use $USER for <username>

Comment: Link is broken.

Comment: why does `qdel -u <username>` fail?

Comment: This was a *long* time ago, I honestly don't remember why. Sorry

Answer (score 60):

Building on what Gabriel answered:

```
qselect -u <username> | xargs qdel

qselect -u <username> -s <state> | xargs qdel
```

`<state>` would be `R` for running jobs only.

qselect will allow you to select job based on other criterias, like ressources asked (-l), destination queue (-q) ...

```
qdel -u <username>
```

will only work with **SGE**

Comment: why does `qdel -u <username>` fail?

Comment: the second solution did not work for me...

Answer (score 14):

sometimes a simple `grep/cut` can help too:

`qstat | grep $USER | cut -d. -f1 | xargs qdel`

This way we can also `grep` on a particular keyword for the jobs and delete them.

HTH

Comment: I use this all of the time because it adds a lot of flexibility for other grep searches.

Comment: why does `qdel -u <username>` fail?

Comment: You may need to adjust the delimiter and field number depending on what your `qstat` output looks like. For example, for me it starts with two space characters and so I use `qstat | grep $USER | cut -d' ' -f3 | xargs qdel`.

Answer (score 8):

Try

```
$ qdel {id1..id2}
```

So for example:

```
$ qdel {1148613..1148650}
```

Answer (score 4):

For UGE:

qstat -u  | gawk '{print $1}' | xargs qdel

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility is to do `qdel all`. It deletes all jobs from everyone. When you don't have access for other people's job, it deletes only your jobs.

It is not the most beautiful solution, but it is surely the shortest!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `The job all of user(s) <user> does not exist`.

Comment: Works for me.  Even if the system reports "unauthorized," it does as guhur states and deletes only your jobs.

Answer (score 2):

```
# Delete all jobs owned by the current user.
# 
# Command breakdown:
# ------------------
#
# qselect
# -u selects all jobs that belong to the current user
# -s EHQRTW selects all job states except for Complete
#
# xargs
# --no-run-if-empty Do not run qdel if the result set is empty
#                   to avoid triggering a usage error.
#
# qdel
# -a delete jobs asynchronously
#
# The backslashes are a trick to avoid matching any shell aliases.

\qselect -u $(whoami) -s EHQRTW | \xargs --no-run-if-empty \qdel -a
```

Answer (score -1):

```
qstat | cut -d. -f1 | sed "s;   \(.*\) 0;qdel \1;" | bash
```

sed's power.

Answer (score -2):

Just use the following command:

```
qdel all
```

It will cancel all jobs running on cluster.