# Cancel all waiting jobs with qsub

Tags: cluster-computing, batch-processing, qsub

I have submitted a lot of jobs to `qsub` and I want to cancel all those not currently running. Is there a way to do this without knowing all the jobIDs?

The answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28857807/use-qdel-to-delete-all-my-jobs-at-once-not-one-at-a-time) prompted me to try

```
qselect -u username -s qw | xargs qdel
```

but this did not work, and I do not want to accidentally delete my currently running jobs.

Answer (score 1):

The below combination worked for me, the output is dependant on the state of the job.

qstat -u  | grep "state of the job"  | awk 'print{ $1 }' | tr '\n' ' ' | xargs qdel

1. qstat -u : displays all the jobs with respect the user.
2. grep "state of the job" : Returns the line containing the state of the job. (r , qw and so on)
3. awk 'print{ $1 }' : Print the first column. (In my case 1st column is Job ID)
4. tr '\n' ' ' :  Substitute the new line character with space.
5. xargs qdel : Delete the jobs.

Comment: Mistyped the awk command. Should be - awk '{print $1}'